# How to check if navigation controller is pushed or is a root view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push, navigationcontroller

I want to check if the view controller i am in is root view controller or is pushed on some navigation controller.

Comment: check `self.navigationController.viewControllers` it will give you array of your pushed navigation viewcontrollers

Comment: You can use `self.navigationController.topViewController == self` to check if it is the `rootViewController`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`[self.navigationController viewControllers];`

will return an array of all the viewControllers on the stack. Simply compare the first element in this array to see is the controller the root or not.

e.g.

```
UIViewController *vc = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] firstObject];

if([vc isEqual: <viewController to check> ])
{
    // code here
}
```

EDIT: Add Swift

```
let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first
if vc == self.navigationController?.visibleViewController {
    //Code Here
}
```

Comment: Note that this answer is correct, answers below are not. When the stack has > 1 element, there is *still* a root view controller living there at the top of that stack!

Comment: @RobP - I agree that root controller will be living at the 0th index of stack even when stack has >1 element. But as current view controller i.e. topViewController can be root only when it is the only controller in stack. In situation when stack >1 element, topViewController will always be different than the root controller. In this answer _Simon_ is checking if a particular view controller is equal to root controller or not, which is not the question being asked.

Comment: @Gandalf the question asked was, is a given viewController the root or not. Which is what i've answered. There are other ways to do this granted, but this isn't incorrect

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin - No, i do not mean it is incorrect, but the question was __"if the view controller i am in is root"__, which means current or topViewController or the last object in navigation stack. For that to be root it has to be firstObject of stack as root will always live at 0th index. I hope you got my point.

Comment: @Gandalf i'm sorry no I don't understand. Your previous comment says that what I have provided is not what the question asked. The user wants to know is the current viewController the root. He can take my code and add `self` into the placeholder in the if check and it will work, because my code will compare the 2 objects and return true if they are the same. The position in the navigation stack is irrelevant to my answer

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin - [Can you come to this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/66483/navigation-controller-stak?tab=general) for further discussion

Comment: the problem is the definition of "current" -- it should mean "code is currently executing in". not "is currently topmost or visible"

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you push any view controller via navigation controller, it manages these view controllers on a stack which is maintained in *Last In First Out* manner. So if your current view controller is root controller than there can be only one object in the stack. You can check that stack via this code

```
if([self.navigationController.viewControllers count] == 1)  {  
   //Current view controller is root controller  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

in your current View controller's viewDidLoad just check `self.navigationController.viewControllers.count == 1` mean you are currently in rootview of your navigationstack. make sure you haven't present viewcontroller.

```
if(self.navigationController.viewControllers.count == 1)
{
    //do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With respect to @Simon answer, I'm adding my answer, to check when you're using some drawer menu, this may help you to find exact root view controller check.

```
- (BOOL) checkImRoot:(id)controller {
    if(self.window.rootViewController) {
        if(self.window.rootViewController == (UIViewController *)controller) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

In example, I'm adding this method in app delegate file, and calling it like this to check,

```
if([[AppDelegate shareDelegate] checkImRoot:self]) {
     //Yeah, I'm a root vc
}else{
     //Noo, I'm a child vc
}
```

Comment: Don't you have an extra `self.window.rootViewController`?! Is that a mistake?

Comment: Nope. It's not a mistake. I am simply accessing the `window` property.

Comment: I still don't get it. You can just write it using the 2nd line...and if it's not true then just return `nil`. Why have the extra line?!

Comment: @Honey, what is `rootViewController` will be `nil`? Then our comparison might crash our code.

Comment: Hah, you're right. I'm coming from a Swift world where the `rootViewController` is an optional...